# Minimize number of lattice paths below a given path

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Every north-east lattice path (NE-path) $v$ from $(0,0)$ to $(k, a)$ can be identified with a sequence $0 \le \lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le . . . \le \lambda_k\le a$, that represent the hight of each step. There is a well known formula for the number of NE-paths from $(0,0)$ to $(k, a)$ *below* the $v$, namely
$$ \ell(v)= \det_{1 \le i,j \le k} \left( \binom{\lambda_i+1}{j-i+1} \right).$$
Now my question is, for a fixed endpoint $(k,a)$, and a fixed number $n>a$, is it known which shape $0 \le \lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le . . . \le \lambda_k$ with $\lambda_1+ \dots + \lambda_k+a=n$ that gives the smallest value for $\ell(v)$? I. e. which shape should I give my path, so that there is as few paths below it as possible?

Comment: I do not understand the question: isn't there just one path for $\lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_{k-1}=0$ and $\lambda_k=n$?  Or did you mean to set $\lambda_k = k$?

Comment: Oops, good point! I meant also to fix the endpoint. I will edit the question. @MartinRubey

Comment: @Mari possibly you mean $\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_k=n$, without $a$? This sounds more natural (we fix the area of the Young diagram) for me.